# Concourse error - discovering any new version loop

Tags: concourse

Has anyone encountered an infinite  loop`discovering any new versions` when building? I suspect there's an issue with one of the workers, does this worker config look ok? Installing the binary - my worker config is shown below.Fly workers list returns nothing.

```
    concourse:
      worker:
        config:
          name: ci_worker01
          bind-ip: 0.0.0.0
          bind-port: 7777
          tsa-host: 127.0.0.1
          tsa-port: 2222
          tsa-public-key: /opt/concourse/.ssh/id_web_rsa.pub
          tsa-worker-private-key: /opt/concourse/.ssh/id_worker_rsa
        service: True
```

Comment: If `fly workers` is returning nothing that means that you are failing to register your worker with atc. You should check your worker logs to see what went wrong.

Comment: I'm having the same issue in a kubernetes installation. Did you solve the issue?